# ReactJS is there any way of looping through a github pages directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I am developing a single paged website which displays the contents of several JSON files in ReactJS. I need to loop through /json which contains the files and display these as a list. These files may change so this needs to be dynamic.

I was able to get this working using a nodeJS back end server. However my spec has changed and now this site has to be hosted on github pages, therefore the back end approach will not work. Does anyone know of any way I can access the directory in React, I have looked and cannot seem to find any way of doing this.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: No. You can't. You need server side language for this. Take an effort searching with node.js

Comment: @BradeyWhitlock it is swagger generated JSON if that helps

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar if I use node.js surely the final site which is going to be hosted via github pages wouldn't allow the backend as this has to be hosted separately

Comment: I understand this: you want a dynamic site hosted in Github, with a backed that serves a list of files. But afaik, Github sites are static, so want you want to do is impossible... or you could have an index file that gets updated every time a JSON file is created/deleted, so your React client could read it to get the updated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access any filesystem without a proxy (like Node.js) from a browser. React is just a series of literal definitions, interpreted by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want with React and [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

You can also dig in SO with [[github-api] react](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D%20react)